# A way to make SVG style attributes take precedence over CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG within a document that uses style attributes ('fill', 'stroke'). I also have a CSS that styles SVG elements. I want the SVG's attributes to trump the CSS. I can't change the CSS (or remove it) or the SVG. Is there a solution? Something like adding a class to the SVG which will hide CSS (but not something where I need to start styling based on the class, I need the attributes to determine the style)?

Comment: If you can change neither the SVG nor the CSS, I'm afraid you're out of options.

Comment: maybe some JS to transform the attribute to inline style and you will have a higher specificity